# Transforming a json format variable into a javascript array

Tags: javascript, django, arrays, json, string

I am using the Django framework to build a website.

In the Python file (views.py) I send to the Javascript function an array that has been transformed to json data

Python:

```
json_data=[1,2,3]
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(json_data), mimetype='application/json')
```

Then, in Javascript I display the json data in the html.

JavaScript:

```
function get_variable(){ 

  $.get("/xhr_test/json/", function(json_data) {
    $('.square').append('<p> ' + json_data  + ' </p>');});
};
```

So far everything works. However, I would like to convert the "json_data", which I believe is a string, into an array.

I tried doing this:

```
function get_variable(){ 

  $.get("/xhr_test/json/", function(json_data) {
    var array = json_data.split(',');
    $('.square').append('<p> ' + array[0]+ ' </p>');});
};
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Can someone please explain to me what could I do to convert the "json_data" variable into an array in JavaScript?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: JSON is an acronym for JavaScript Object Notation, so you can just `JSON.parse(json_data);` to get the array/object that was sent as a string...

Comment: I tried doing "var array = JSON.parse(json_data);" But then I try printing "    $('.square').append('<p> ' + array[0]  + ' </p>');" And it doesn't work

Comment: What does the browser console say when you try to do this? WHat errors occur? WHat does "doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send around data in JSON format it is a string (the main data), but a string formated in such a way that it's easy to recover the data with the original types (ie, your array). Javascript and jquery have different ways to do that. Using jQuery,getJSON is probably the most direct:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

You can use your browsers javascript console to see what exactly do your JS variables look like.

Answer (score 1):

"this doesn't work" it's too vague...
Anyway, if I understood your problem, you are dealing with a string, not a JavaScript array... you have to evaluate the data returned from the ajax call:

```
var theJavaScriptArray = eval('(' + json_data + ')');
```

or better... use **jQuery.ajax** and specify json as dataType: [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: what are you trying to say? :P

Comment: Looks to me like he's questioning your use of `eval`; can't say I blame him. `JSON.parse` or, assuming it's always an array of numbers, `String#split` would make a lot more sense.

Comment: JSON.parse is not crossbrowser! ;)

Comment: ... "eval is evil" MUST be demystified! :D

Answer (score 1):

In the end, thanks to Zah I discovered the "javascript console", which I didn't know it existed.

I could see that the error was that the "json_data" variable was not a string.

So this is the solution that worked for me:

```
function get_variable(){ 
  $.get("/xhr_test/json/", function(json_data) {
    var b=json_data.toString().split(',');
    $('.square').append('<p> ' + b[0]  + ' </p>');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a shorthand in jQuery to parse the json string automatically: [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
$.getJSON('/xhr_test/json/', function(data) {
     console.log(data);  // Here data is already a JavaScript object
});
```

This is basically the same as:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/xhr_test/json/",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);  // Here data is already a JavaScript object
    }
});
```

Which again is about the same as:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/xhr_test/json/",
    success: function(data) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);  // Here data is a string
        console.log(data);  // And json is JavaScript object
    }
});
```